# RewriteRule in htaccess rename

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello all i want to make, that user goes to directory:

> www.myweb.com/invites/User

It would work as

> www.myweb.com/invites/index.php?u=User

I tried something, but doesn't work.

Comment: did you try something already? let us know

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lrgp.lt [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lrgp.lt/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(Invites)/([^.]*) $1/index.php?u=$2 [L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

In the folder `invites`, create a `.htaccess` file or use apache rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The rule is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?u=$1
```